# Mount ext3 from remote Windows machine (XP/Vista/7) through ssh?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, mount

Is it possible to mount external ext3 network drive from Windows through ssh/sftp ?

I would like to avoid samba/cifs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things that aren't Samba come to mind:

- NFS, via Client Services for NFS for Windows (see this [HOWTO](http://sagehacks.wordpress.com/2009/01/21/howto-mount-nfs-shares-under-windows-7/))
- [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/), formerly known as SFTPDrive

There's also the brilliant "sort of VPN over SSH" solution [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle#readme), if you have a Linux-ish gateway on the remote network.

Comment: NFS for Windows looks promising as for me. Need to try.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be done using sshfs. It is available for all platforms.
http://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/

Answer (score 0):

did try with following tools https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/

Comment: As I understood from the description of this product, it works only on local machine and there is no SSH support.